# event.preventDefault() not working on mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mozilla

I'm having problems with a function that works fine in Google Chrome, but sucks in Mozilla:

The JavaScript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function gid(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function validate() {
        var x = document.forms["frmSurvey"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");            

        if((gid('0_stars').checked==true) || (gid('1_stars').checked==true) || (gid('2_stars').checked==true) || (gid('3_stars').checked==true) || (gid('4_stars').checked==true)) {
            if((gid('comment').value != '') && (gid('email').value != '') && (gid('name').value != '')) {
                if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                    alert("Not a valid e-mail address. Please write a valid e-mail address!");
                    return false;
               } else {
                    document.getElementById("frmSurvey").submit();
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('You haven`t completed the mandatory fields. Please make sure that you complete the form corectly! Thank you!');
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('You haven`t completed the mandatory fields. Please make sure that you complete the form corectly! Thank you!');
            return false;
        }
    }       
</script>
```

And the form is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" id="frmSurvey" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validate();"> 
    ...
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

Is there any methods to replace this function with another? I already tried return false; but then it doesn't submit at all!

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but i usually pass event into the function..

In your case validate(event) { event.preventDefault() }
onsubmit="validate(event)"

Comment: I would suggest removing the onsubmit from the form tag, and instead make an event listener on the submit button itself such as `$("#mysubmitid").click(function(){ validate(); });`

Comment: Have you tried event.stopPropagation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return true` to the end of `validate`.

Then change:

```
onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validate();"
```

... to :

```
onsubmit="return validate();"
```

This will cause the form to submit only if it has been validated.

**Edit**

Once you've done this, you can remove this line from `validate()`:

```
document.getElementById("frmSurvey").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the onsubmit in the form element and add this to you js file.

```
 $('#frmSurvey').submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
 });
```